# APS missing entitlements

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Just received an email from Apple stating that my app is (copied below)
Ok no problem. I deleted my old provisioning profile, made sure the new one has an aps key

```
**<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>**
```

and resubmitted again.
And of course I received the same message. 
How should I proceed? Any ideas?

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "iPicture Frames LT". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish
>   to correct the following issues in your next delivery: Missing Push
>   Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to
>   register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
>   signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API. If you would like to
>   update your binary for this app, you can reject this binary from the
>   Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting your binary
>   will remove your app from the review queue and the review process will
>   start over from the beginning when you resubmit your binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MULTIPLE trials of deleting files, cleaning project and restarting Xcode I managed to submit the app. Uff. finally.